# Why am I getting an UIBarButtonItem customization warning?

Tags: ios, warnings, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uibarmetrics

I have a simple storyboard with a table view inside a navigation view controller that pushes from the table view to another view controller that has a full screen image view. The table view has a prompt text in it's navigation bar. When I tap on the table view cell in the table view I receive the warning below. I'm not customizing the back button at all. I created a sample project showing the issue.

https://github.com/stevemoser/UIBarButtonItemCustomizationWarningExampleProject

Anyone have an idea why I'm receiving this warning?

> UIBarButtonItem customization of back button background image for UIBarMetricsDefaultPrompt or UIBarMetricsLandscapePhonePrompt is ignored`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried your code in a lot of combinations: Xcode 5.0.2 \ beta one, iPhone 5 \ iPhone 5s and various Simulators. This issue isn't reproducible when using new beta iOS SDK, so seems like this bug was fixed and you don't have to worry about it anymore.

Comment: Excellent. I'm not currently using the iOS 7.1 betas, but I trust you're correct. I'll award the bounty in the 22 hours.

Comment: You have my word, tested on both device with 7.1b3 iOS and Simulator. Glad to help!