# Why black screen display between navigationBar and view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, translucency

In my project have Two View Controller(First & Second) embed in a navigation controller and Translucent is set NO. but i have used prompt in First ViewController.

I used AutoLayout. if you know the solution with and without AutoLayout i will really happy

[image]

[image]

when i push to second viewcontroller. i got some black screen under navigation bar

[image]

I tried plenty of concept but any helped.

help me How to  fix.

**NOTE:**

Don't say set Translucent is YES. I know if i set yes it works perfectly. but i need achieve with Translucent is NO

Updated 1: Images are updated.

Comment: So if the black space is below your navigation bar.. maybe your blue view is too short?

Comment: that is it. i know. i want why is coming

Comment: Why is your navigation bar so huge in the first VC? ...

Comment: i used prompt in my navigationbar

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error and got an error message in my console. After googling that error msg I found the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103071/why-am-i-getting-an-uibarbuttonitem-customization-warning

Seems like it was fixed in iOS7.1

Comment: this answer was not in my question. i know already the warning is not a issue for me.

Comment: What iOS Version do you run?

Comment: iOS 7 & iPhone 4 inch

Comment: Then the answer to your question might be "because you don't have the latest iOS Version"

Comment: No buddy. you said totally wrong

Comment: it is depends on Translucent problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used this code. but i won't any hardcode solution. if you have know any other solution please share

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height+20, 320, 504);
}];
```

Answer (score 4):

I have turned off Autolayout - and found following solution

**ViewController First**

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
     self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

}
```

**ViewController Second**

```
 -(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
 {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    appDelegate.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 64.0, 320.0, 504.0);

 }
```

I hope this helps, for Autolayout it works fine as well

Comment: i know this approach i tried with this one. i need optimized way. don't need for hardcode any values

Answer (score -1):

try to  set your navigationView's `backgroundColor`.